# Trying to pull out names of lists which have a low value. Can't get logic to work

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Trying to print out which days have less than 7 hours. I've tried several different ways of making it work to no avail.

```
day_one_list = ['Day 1', 5]
day_two_list = ['Day 2', 8]
day_three_list = ['Day 3', 6]
day_four_list = ['Day 4', 8]
day_five_list = ['Day 5',2]
    
    
 def slack_days(day_one_list, day_two_list, day_three_list, day_four_list, day_five_list):
        days_list = [day_one_list, day_two_list, day_three_list, day_four_list, day_five_list] 
            for name, hours in days_list:
                if hours < 7:
                    print(f"On {name} you worked {hours}.")

slack_days(day_one_list, day_two_list, day_three_list, day_four_list, day_five_list)
```

Comment: Print the hours variable before the if statement. What do you see?

Comment: You know you can nest lists, right? You don't need five variables here.

Comment: It's part of a larger program I'm making for an assignment. I know I am not doing it in the most efficient way - I'm still a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for name, hours in days_list` doesn't unpack the nested lists.

Try the following

```
def slack_days(*args):
    for day in args:
        if day[1] < 7:
            print(f"On {day[0]} you worked {day[1]}.")

slack_days(day_one_list, day_two_list, day_three_list, day_four_list, day_five_list)
```

Or just use a regular, flat list

```
day_hours = [5,8,6,8,2]
for day, hour in enumerate(day_hours):
    if hour < 7:
        print(f"On day {day+1} you worked {hour}.")
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved me a lot of headache!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could use a dict :)

```py
def slack_days(days): return [
    f'On {day} you worked {hours} hours' 
    for day,hours in days.items()
    if hours < 7
]

days = {
    'Day 1': 5,
    'Day 2': 8,
    'Day 3': 6,
    'Day 4': 8,
    'Day 5': 2,
}

for output in slack_days(days);
    print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can represent days as a tuple and append it to a list and do a list comprehension.

```
days = [('day1', 5), ('day2', 6), ('day3', 9), ('day4', 2)]
less_seven = [i[0] for i in days if i[1] < 7]
print(less_seven)
```

output:

```
['day1', 'day2', 'day4']
```